# Form Parameters

Tags: forms

Some forms like the `user_login` form have `$form` and `&$form_state` for parameters. The Drupal 7 Module Development book also have the 2 parameters in their example. But in the [Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826), the example only have the `&$form_state` parameter. In what cases should there be 2 parameters and in what cases should there be only 1 parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Quickstart Guide" you linked to is for Drupal 6.

Drupal 6 form signature:

```
function MYMODULE_some_form(&$form_state) {
  // ...
}
```

Drupal 7 form signature:

```
function MYMODULE_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // ...
}
```

Nothing more to it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! What's the link of the Drupal 7 Quickstart Guide? The link in the [Drupal 7 Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) leads to the Drupal 6 Quickstart Guide, that's why I initially thought it was just the same.

Comment: Unless my Google-fu is seriously letting me down there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Drupal 7...You might start [here](http://drupal.org/node/1043838) though, and visit the links on that page they look promising